# Touchpad dosn't work on Lenovo V330-15IKB

Tags: 16.04, grub2, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

the touchpad on my laptop just went wrong. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and my machine runs on dualboots. Works on Windows, the touchpad only, not on Linux. I tried adjusting the grub configuration, but unfortunately I couldn't fix it. Then I reinstalled the entire xorg service and it still isn't good. Do you have any tips for what's wrong?

Comment: This link can be helpful: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/V330-15IKB-touchpad-does-not-work-with-ubuntu-18-04-amp-16-04/td-p/4142420

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue here: [Touchpad not working after system update (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195267/touchpad-not-working-after-system-update-18-04) Not sure if it's the same issue, but it might help